# SUM() 3 columns with alias into a fourth one

Tags: sql-server-2014, stored-procedures

This is one part of my procedure:

```
 select nome, 

       --casos expedidos (- 3 meses)
       isnull((SELECT      count(cod_rep)    
                    FROM   tbReps 
                    where  tbreps.cod_status = 7
                    and          tbreps.cod_perito_primeiro=cod_usuario
                    AND          (MONTH(tbreps.datahora_emissao) = MONTH(@DATA1) 
                    AND          YEAR(TBREPS.datahora_emissao) = YEAR(@DATA1))),0) as Laudos_Expedidos1,


       --casos expedidos (- 2 meses)
       isnull((SELECT      count(cod_rep)    
                    FROM   tbReps 
                    where  tbreps.cod_status = 7
                    and          tbreps.cod_perito_primeiro=cod_usuario
                    AND          (MONTH(tbreps.datahora_emissao) = MONTH(@DATA2)
                    AND          YEAR(TBREPS.datahora_emissao) = YEAR(@DATA2))),0) as Laudos_Expedidos2,



       --casos expedidos (- 1 meses)
       isnull((SELECT      count(cod_rep)    
                    FROM   tbReps 
                    where  tbreps.cod_status = 7
                    and          tbreps.cod_perito_primeiro=cod_usuario
                    AND          (MONTH(tbreps.datahora_emissao) = MONTH(@DATA3)
                    AND          YEAR(TBREPS.datahora_emissao) = YEAR(@DATA3))),0) as Laudos_Expedidos
```

It will create this:

[image]

How can I sum, for example, LAUDOS_EXPEDIDOS1 + LAUDOS_EXPEDIDOS2  Into a 4º column? like this:

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's something really easy. I'm trying to use sum with the aliases, with no success.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot refer to an alias defined in the same `SELECT` list. There are various workarounds. Assuming your query is something like this:

```
select nome, 
       -- various complex expression / subqueries
       <complex_expression_or_subquery>
           as Laudos_Expedidos,
       <complex_expression_or_subquery>
           as Laudos_Expedidos2
from <table_name> ;
```

- Duplicate code. As this is the least attractive solution, for various reasons, I won't add a code sample.
- a derived table or a CTE allows to use the aliases as they are already defined in a previous level:

  ```
  with cte as
  ( select nome, 
           -- various complex expression / subqueries
           <complex_expression_or_subquery>
               as Laudos_Expedidos,
           <complex_expression_or_subquery>
               as Laudos_Expedidos2
    from <table_name>
  ) 
  select c.*,
         c.Laudos_Expedidos + c.Laudos_Expedidos2
             as Total_Laudos_Expedidos
  from cte as c ;
  ```
- Use `CROSS / OUTER APPLY` allows also to refer to previously defined aliases. This offers the possibility of using multiple outer/cross apply subqueries, if you want to use the aliases of the first apply in further calculations. (With the derived/CTE solution, that is also possible but the code usually looks more complicated):

  ```
  select t.nome, 
         f.*,
         g.Total_Laudos_Expedidos,
         f.Laudos_Expedidos / g.Total_Laudos_Expedidos
             as Percent_Expedidos
  from <table_name> as t
    outer apply
      ( select 
            -- various complex expression / subqueries
            <complex_expression_or_subquery>
                as Laudos_Expedidos,
            <complex_expression_or_subquery>
                as Laudos_Expedidos2
      ) as f 
    outer apply
      ( select 
            f.Laudos_Expedidos + f.Laudos_Expedidos2
                as Total_Laudos_Expedidos   
      ) as g ;
  ```

Comment: Hey @Yopercube. Yes I tried with CTE but I got some problems with sintaxes. I used to use it but, anyway...I'm trying to understand how to use `outer apply`. Since I want to return those 3 columns ( Laudos_Expedidos, Laudos_Expedidos2,Laudos_Expedidos3) and one more with the sum, named Laudos_Expedidos_sum, I need to copy those 3 queries again but using outer apply?  Like...`query1`, `query2`,`query3`,`all 3 queries but now using cross apply`? I could understand the logic. I will try to figure out the sintax now. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, just replace each `<complex_expression_or_subquery>` with the respective `isnull(...)` expression. No code needs duplication with this. You just move the code from the `select` list to the `outer apply`.